# Expired Windows Account Password

Tags: windows, password, user-accounts

I need to programatically change my windows admin password without using the login screen.

Essentially we deployed 50+ laptops across our business.
We setup 1 user account and 1 admin account (same password) on each laptop, they're not added to domain etc.  They aren't connected to our network in anyway, we also installed some remote software to control them over the internet.
Essentially, the remote software stopped working yesterday, the only way I can get into the laptop is via some C# program which is running on the laptops under the "user account" credentials.

I did manage to push out a script which would have allowed me access again, but the admin account I setup months ago has expired so I no way to do anything programatically.  If I logged in via the home screen, i could reset the password but this isn't an option. So i need a way to change the password, without the windows login prompt, via the user account, in command line / powershell.
I know the existing admin password, but is there a way to trigger this change from within the user account:

For example:  CHANGEPW.exe -account admin -oldpw pass -newpw passnw

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you:

[change-your-own-expired-password-when-you-cant-login-to-rdp](https://evotec.xyz/how-to-change-your-own-expired-password-when-you-cant-login-to-rdp/)

It's not exactly what you need, the powershell script interactively asks for username, old password, new password. But it can be easily modified to your needs. Also the C++ function used under the hood is mentioned, in case you want to go that way instead of powershell script.